# CurrentItem Method is not working on my inspector

Tags: outlook, add-in, ribbon

I'm creating a Ribbon with a splitbutton which automaticly fills the subject line on an appointmentitem, but I can't seem to do that without creating a new Item. I don't want another window of the calendar to open, I want to use the current one I already opened. Here is my code so far for the splitbutton:

```
Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.TerminAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();     
       Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = inspector.CurrentItem(); 
       appointmentItem.Subject = "Test" ;
```

Comment: When is that code called? In response to a ribbon control event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called when I click on the SplitButton. I already fixed the problem though.

```
var inspector = Globals.TerminAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = inspector;
        appointmentItem.Subject = "Test123";
```

That`s how it´s working now.